# Optim error - initial value in vmmin is not finite

Tags: r, optimization

I have run

```
  'fitdistr(mydata, "Gaussian")'
```

and get the following error message:

```
Error in optim(x = c(34.513, 25.587, 18.251, 52.836, 38.206, 42.395, 47.22,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

However when I run

```
 'fitdistr(mydata,"Normal")'
```

I get the following:

```
  mean           sd     
 39.71581691   23.44081474 
( 0.02856006) ( 0.02019501)
```

How do I fit my data to Gamma and other distributions that are not normal?

Sajni

Comment: Have you tried other inital values when fitting your model with 'Gaussian'? The error message returned by optim() suggests that the function being optimised cannot be evaluated at the current initial values...

Comment: This is really more of a programming question than a statistical one - have a look at the help page by typing `help(fitdistr)` or going to http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html ... The `arguments` section of the help file should answer both of your questions...

Comment: What do you mean by "other inital values... "?

Comment: @sajni: you should definitively read the documentation...
"'par': Initial values for the parameters to be optimized over."

Comment: This question, because it addresses a matter of R programming, would be more suitable for posting on SO.  However, to be acceptable there, it first needs to be rewritten to reflect some research into the help page and to give a fuller account of what is causing the difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

The Gaussian distribution isn't supported (although as you know, the normal distribution is). Have a look at `?fitdistr` after loading the `MASS` package and you will find a list of supported distributions. To fit data to a gamma distribution,

```
require(MASS)    
x <- rgamma(100, shape = 5, rate = 0.1)
fitdistr(x, "gamma")
#     shape         rate   
#  4.43472115   0.09208318 
# (0.60485447) (0.01329746)
```

Comment: (+1) Well, the Gaussian distribution is supported, you just aren't allowed to call it the Gaussian distribution :) I also made a minor edit - hopefully you don't mind

Comment: Exactly! I guess I should have included a smiley face to indicate (mild) sarcasm... ;-)